# How to display properties of base class and subclasses in listbox

Tags: c#

```
public class Animal
{

 public string Name {get;set;}


}

public string Cat : Animal
{

 public int AmountOfTeeth {get;set;}

}


//In Form.cs:

public void showAnimal(){


 var animalList = _animalManager.GetAnimals();


foreach(var animal in animalList)
{

     animalListbox.Items.Add(animal)
}
```

How do I display both Name and AmountOfLegs in the listbox?

Like this: Steven 14

}

Comment: what is the type of animalList ?

Comment: GetAnimals() returns List<Animal>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ListBox` component displays what the `ToString()` method returns. You can change the display by overriding the method

```
public class Cat : Animal // note you probably mistyped "class" here
{
    public int AmountOfTeeth { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + " has " + AmountOfTeeth + " teeth"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I guess I have to override the ToSTring() method in ex. the Dog class and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I love to keep the data entities 'clean' and not to add display only related properties/methods.
What I am usually do is creating local entity just for the display. Lets say AnimalDisplay which gets the base entity in its ctor. With the new entity I can add any prop I want just for the display, or override the ToString() in that mater and use this in the list.

Just another angle on this one...